How to automate execution of Laravel queue worker in Docker container?
I want to run my docker compose and not have to manually execute php artisan queue:work to start my worker. I created 2 service o the first one is my php fpm and the second one is my queue serice which has the same image and the same volume.
  app:
    build:
      context: php
    container_name: laravel_app
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - laravel

  queue:
    build:
      context: php
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html
    command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'php artisan queue:work']
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - app

The service is up but don't receive any job even if i exec manually inside the container artisan queue:work i have "INFO  Processing jobs from the [default] queue." but i don't receive any job. However, when i exec manually the same command inside the app container it works and they have the same volume.
The problem is the connection with redis when the queue service exec queue:work i have this error message in my laravel.log:
    [2024-09-04 19:40:48] local.ERROR: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for redis failed: Name or service not known {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for red
is failed: Name or service not known at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:159)

my redis config is in my .env file present in laravel folder: REDIS_HOST=redis REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379

The Compose file superficially looks correct, except possibly for the networks: of the two services disagreeing (delete all of the networks: blocks in the entire file) (you shouldn't need volumes: for the setup you show).  How do you configure the location of things like the Redis store?

You're right  it's a redis connection problem when my queue service exec queue:work in my laravel log i have :
is failed: Name or service not known at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:159)```
my redis config is in my .env file present in laravel folder:
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

Do you in fact have a container named redis in the Compose file?

yes ! But anyway i did everything in one container using supervisor with 2 tasks: php-fpm and queue:work

You claim that you do have a redis container in your compose file but you have not updated your question to reflect that. It could be that you've misconfigured that, we just can't know.

I would do something like this using supervisord:
Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# do watherever you need to do to setup for laravel
# such as copying files or installing extensions



# Install Supervisor
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]


supervisord.conf:


[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=90
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log



it do not work for me, it has the same behavior

Here is a two-container Docker Compose solution using a dedicated worker container to work the queue which uses YAML anchors and aliases to avoid markup redundancy. The :z option tells Docker that the volume content will be shared between containers. May request changes if not using Octane:
compose.yaml
x-base: &base
  # Alternatively your image
  build:
    context: .
  # Shared volume between main container and worker container
  volumes:
    - .:/app:z

services:
  worker:
    <<: *base
    name: worker
    entrypoint: php artisan queue:work

  main:
    <<: *base
    name: main
    entrypoint: php artisan octane:frankenphp
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

This solution also works on Podman Compose.
Healthcheck
Depending on your setup, you may need to disable healthcheck for the worker container:
healthcheck:
      disable: true

